# How do I add a column to a Table in a row with data from another column?

Tags: mysql, power-query, microsoft-powerbi

I have a query that aggregates `MySQL.Database` output.

[image]

What I would like to do is update the `Table` in `Data` to contain the value of `Schema` for each row in the Table.

I think it would be something to do with one of the `Table.*` functions.  Specifically

```
= Table.TransformColumns(OrganizationTables, { [what goes here???] })
```

An identity transform is

```
= Table.TransformColumns(OrganizationTables, { "Data", (row) as table => row })
```

This didn't work

```
= Table.TransformColumns(
    OrganizationTables, 
    { 
      "Data", 
      (row) as table => Table.AddColumn(row, "schema", each OrganizationTables[Schema] )
     }
  )
```

nor this

```
= Table.TransformColumns(
    OrganizationTables, 
    { 
      "Data", 
      (row) as table => Table.AddColumn(row, "schema", each [Schema] )
     }
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of transforming a column I had to transform the whole row since I only needed to add it to the resulting table with the added schema column, I disregarded the rest of the fields of the row and just got a `list` of `tables`

```
AddedSchemaColumnInData = Table.TransformRows(OrganizationTables, (row) as table =>  Table.AddColumn(row[Data], "schema", (d) => row[Schema]))
CombineData = Table.Combine(AddedSchemaColumnInData),
```

Answer (score 0):

The low-code/citizen developer approach would be just to hit the **Expand** button in the column header for your **Data** column.

That will insert new columns and rows for all the columns and rows found in each nested table in that column. The existing columns will be preserved and "filled down" onto all the inserted rows.